# Where to do a typedef when using multiple .h files

Tags: c

I was wondering where I would need to do a typedef when using multiple .h files in c language. I have a project to do and have decided to divide the functions in to two separate .c and .h files to make it easier to locate a certain function. But the problem I an having is I need to define two type using typedef, and the both the header files need to know what this type is otherwise I get errors saying type unknown or something similar. I have tried putting the typedef in a separate .h file.

```
//in type.h
typedef struct
{
    int val;   /*Valeur de la case (0 si vide)*/
    int n_candidats;  /*Nombre de candidats possibles*/
    int candidats[9];  /*liste de candidats*/
} T_case;

typedef struct
{
    T_case grille[81]; /*vecteur de 81 cases*/
} T_sudoku;
```

But when I include it in my other .h files it won't work, it comes up with loads of errors like, T_case was previously defined here, conflicting types for .., note: expected ‘T_sudoku’ but argument is of type ‘T_sudoku’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be caused by including the .h file in multiple .c file.
Try making the .h file like this

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H

/// put all the definitions of the .h file here
#endif
```

Comment: Ok thanks, do I do that for all the .h files or just the one in which I use typedef?

Comment: 1) The answer to your original question: put the "typedef" in whatever header makes sense (e.g. "a.h").  Then #include it in the other header (e.g. "b.h").  2) The answer to "#ifndef FILENAME_H" - you should *always* use this convention, in *all* your headers.  PS: they're called "include guards".  You can read more about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: It is a good practice doing it for all the header files. As it prevents multiple definitions of the same variable.

Comment: Ok done thatm and all the errors about that are gone I thinkm everything knows what type it is ad stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are including `type.h` multiple times (ex. in the other headers and again in the .c file). Thus, there are multiple typedefs.

To fix this, use an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or [#pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) at the top of the header file.

Comment: ["#pragma once"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) is dffererent from ["include guards"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).  I would suggest avoiding #pragma once: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC8

Comment: @FoggyDay: It doesn't say why it is obsolete. I find it much **much** more practical and safe than conventional guards.

Comment: @FoggyDay I changed the text. However, I find #pragma once the better choice. It is much simpler to implement and avoids problems such as accidentally having the same name twice.